# How to highlight submenu jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have menu and highlighting works there fine, but when I in some subpage main menu item is not highlighted.
My code:

```
<ul class="sidebar-nav sidebar-nav-icons">
  <li><a href='/'><i></i>bla bla</a></li>
  <li><a href="Shipments"><i></i>bla bla</a></li>
</ul>
```

My script:

```
$(function() {
  var url = window.location.href;
  $(".sidebar-nav-icons a").each(function() {
    if (url == (this.href)) {
      $(this).closest("li").addClass("active");
    }
  });
});
```

In Shipments page a have a link to next page with link "Shipments/Shipment".
When I'm in Shipments page menu item is highlighted, but when I'm in Shipment it's not. How to create it? Thanks

Comment: and what happens when you debug this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you make an equals comparison between the URL and the anchor's href, the `active` class will only be applied if the page is the same.

A possible approach would be to check if the URL **starts with** the anchor's href.

```js
var url = window.location.href;
$(".sidebar-nav-icons a").each(function () {
    if (url.startsWith(this.href)) {
        $(this).closest("li").addClass("active");
    }
});
```

Edit: if you're using relative paths, you can use `windows.location.pathname` instead of `window.location.href`.

Comment: Note: IE won't support `startsWith`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [startsWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) function instead of equality check:

```js
if (url.startsWith(this.href)) {
    // your highlight logic goes here
}
```